# HTML 5 using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```js
unction calculate() {
var base = document.getElementById("base1").value;
var height = document.getElementById("altura").value;
 var base1=  document.getElementById("base1").value;
var height1 =  document.getElementById("height1").value;
 
  var area = base * height / 2;
  document.getElementById("area").innerHTML = area;
  
}


var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

var base = base1 * 100; 
var height = height1* 100; 
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(base, 0); 

ctx.moveTo(base, 0); 
ctx.lineTo(base / 2, height);

ctx.moveTo(base / 2, height);
ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Triangle</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <!-- This is the HTML5 canvas. We need to specify the its width and height but feel free to change them -->
 <canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=300></canvas>
<input id="base1" placeholder="Input base1 length">
<input id="height1" placeholder="Input height1 length">
<button type="button" id="submit" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
   <p>The area is <span id="area"></span></p>
    
 </body>
</html>
```

I have a question, I'm building up a website and I need to represent the area of a a triangle based on the equation `Area = bh/2` I'm trying to use canvas to generate the shape and I have been looking a lot for a piece of code that I can use but so far nothing.

So far I have created 3 variables.

```
var base

var height
```

I have draw the triangle separate from this 2 var using canvas - however on this page the user is supposed to fill out the base and the height by inputting the numbers he would like to calculate and I haven't find a way to correlate the ideas around this.

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried? Show your [mcve] and tell us what you can't seem to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

To use the HTML5 canvas you need to first create a canvas element in your HTML code and then get it in your JS code using document.getElementById().

Then you need to get a reference to the 2d context by using `canvas.getContext("2d")` so that you can use it to draw on the canvas. Then you define your triangle path by using the following functions: `ctx.moveTo()` and `ctx.lineTo()`.

I suggest you read about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp
or here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial

Anyway the following code might suit your needs:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"); // Get the 2d context which we will use for drawing

var base = 100; // Your base length
var height = 100; // Your height length

//TIP: I suggest multiplying them by some variable so that they look bigger

ctx.moveTo(0, 0); // This methods move an imaginary "pen" to the location 0, 0
ctx.lineTo(base, 0); // And this method moves that imaginary "pen" to the location base, 0 while also creating a line between those points.

ctx.moveTo(base, 0); // We start the next line at the end of the base
ctx.lineTo(base / 2, height); // And we finish it at the middle point of the base but height pixels below it and that's why the triangle will be isosceles triangle(2 of its sides will be equal)

ctx.moveTo(base / 2, height); // And the final line begins and the end of the previous
ctx.lineTo(0, 0); // And ends in the beggining of the first

// Basically we define a path from (0, 0) to (base, 0) to (base / 2, height) to (0, 0) which closes your triangle 

ctx.stroke(); // This method colors the path so that the triangle won't appear white
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Triangle</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- This is the HTML5 canvas. We need to specify the its width and height but feel free to change them -->
    <canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=300></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you know how can i convert the variables base and height to an input number that will be enter by the user?

Comment: @JohansselPeguero you should use document.getElementId(). Working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NJReEq

Comment: As you can see i have created 2 different variables base1 and height1 I am trying to multiply var base,  var height times the input capture on the previous 2 variables but I am getting no results.